# Trying to understand the Assembly implementation of the alloca() function on x86

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, alloca

I am very new to assembly and I am currently reading a book called *Reverse Engineering for Beginners* and I got to the part that talks about memory allocation on the stack.
I understand (I think) the concept of stack allocation but in the example there was something that I didn't understood and I'll be happy if anyone here can help.

The book give this function as an example:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#include <alloca.h> // GCC
#else
#include <malloc.h> // MSVC
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
void f()
{
    char *buf=(char*)alloca (600);
#ifdef __GNUC__
    snprintf (buf, 600, "hi! %d, %d, %d\n", 1, 2, 3); // GCC
#else
    _snprintf (buf, 600, "hi! %d, %d, %d\n", 1, 2, 3); // MSVC
#endif
    puts (buf);
};
```

I understand what the C function does. It allocates 600 bytes of memory on the stack and than writes to that space the string "hi!" using the `_snprintf`  function. Then the function prints it.

All good for now. After that the book gives the assembly implementation that the MSVC compiler produced and the code looks like this:

```asm
mov eax, 600 ; 00000258H
call __alloca_probe_16
mov esi, esp
push 3
push 2
push 1
push OFFSET $SG2672
push 600 ; 00000258H
push esi
call __snprintf
push esi
call _puts
add esp, 28
```

Here I understand that the `EAX` register will contain the argument for the `__alloca_probe_16` function.
but now something doesn't make sence to me. From what I understand the function `__alloca_probe_16` basically just subtracts the number of bytes that is in the value of `EAX` from `ESP`.

So for example if `ESP` points to 1000 now it points to 400. Then we store the 400 into `ESI` and start pushing arguments of `_snprintf` to the stack and `ESI` is pointing to the location of where the function needs to start writing data to.
So my problem is this, if both the `ESP` and `ESI` registers point to 400 and I allocated memory from 1000-400 (600 bytes), and I start pushing things onto the stack, won't they go in to the position starting from 400 and decreasing? I mean, why did it subtract 600 byte if it is not using them?
In my eyes this is how the stack looks like after the `push esi` line.

```
|          400          |
|          600          |
|    adrr of string     |
|           1           |
|           2           |
|           3           | 400 , ESP , ESI
|                       | ...
|_______________________| 1000
```

I  know that I am probably wrong and didn't understand something right because I don't think the book is wrong, I'll be happy if someone can help me to understand what is happening in this assembly code.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the stack looks like. What do you believe is wrong with this picture? What do you find surprising about it?

Comment: my question is why did i allocated the 600 bytes if i don't use it?

Comment: You passed a pointer to those bytes as the first argument of `snprintf`. That's `400` at the top of your picture. `snprintf` will write the output into those bytes.

Comment: So the snprintf write the data to [ESI + 600] ,[ESI+601] etc' until it get to the \0 byte?
or it's starts from 400 and the 401 402 etc?

Comment: `snprintf` will write data to `400`, `401` and so on, where `400` is its first argument, the value at the top of the stack when it's called. But no farther than `400+600`, where `600` is its second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so for example if the ESP points to 1000 now it points to 400. then we store the 400 into ESI and start pushing arguments of the _snprintf to the stack and ESI is pointing to the location of where the function needs to start writing data to.

Right.

> So my problem is this, if both the ESP and ESI registers point to 400 and I allocated memory from 1000-400 (600 bytes), and I start pushing thing into the stack, won't they go in to the position starting from 400 and decreasing?

Yes, certainly they will.

> I mean , we did I subtracted 600 byte if i am not using them?

You haven't used that space *yet*, but you've made it available so that `snprintf` has a place to write the string it produces, and you passed it address 400 (which was in ESI) to tell it to do so.  When `snprintf` returns, the string `"hi! 1, 2, 3 \n"` will be stored starting at address 400.

Of course you didn't really need 600 bytes for such a short string; that's just an example for illustration.  You could make it smaller if you want.